# What is the use of `${}` in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I sometimes see this kind of syntax inside backticks in TypeScript component files in Angular projects:

```
<div ${selector} [inDemo]="false" [config]="demoConfig">Demo Content</div>
```

Can somebody explain me this specific attribute `${}`?

How does it work and when should I use it?

Comment: are you sure its not # ???

Comment: Probably just a template string: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#string. A bit more context would help.

Comment: It's a TypeScript feature (string interpolation) and therefore only works for inline templates (`template: '...',` but not for external templates `templateUrl: './my_component.html'`, )

Comment: Not `#` (ElementRef) but `${}`. I think it's indeed a TypeScript feature. I will dive more into it..

Comment: just its es6 javascript feature :-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is it technically correct to call this a "TypeScript" feature?

Answer (score 3):

It's called template literals, It is a feature of ECMASCRIPT6 (ECMASCRIPT2015)

Without using it, you can concat a string with some variables by:

```
var a = 10, b = 15;
var string = "a equals to " + a + " and b equals to " + b;
```

By using template litteral, it will be simpler:

```
var a = 10, b = 15;
var string = `a equals to ${a} and b equals to ${b}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals;

The are serve for writing multi-line strings:

```
`string text`

`string text line 1  
string text line 2`

`string text ${expression} string text`

tag`string text ${expression} string text`
```